# Oracle Virtualbox problems in setup

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, installation

I have Windows 8 Pro and I was trying to install oracle virtualbox Version 4.3.12. for the genymotion emulator . While installing the installation bar goes till copying files and then suddenly it appears to roll back. Then at final VM VirtualBox 4.1.12 setup wizard ended.

> Prematurely because of an error.Your system has not been modified.Please install at another time.

I have tried to install it lot of time.
I have done the following:

1. Run as administrator .
2. Changed the MaxNumFilters from 0 to 8 decimal .
3. I installed oracle virtualbox in another laptop with windows 7 and it's worked fine. I don't know why it doesn't work in my windows 8 pro ?
4. I tried previous versions of oracle virtualbox, but I got the same error .

Any ideas are appreciated.